# Xamarin - VS for Mac - When compiling i get this error: Error APT0000: obj/Debug/res/ renderers

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.android

For some reason, there is a space in the path and I can't figure out from where it is, so the compilation fails.

Any help will be great.

Note: the project was started in xamarin for windows and i am using now vs.net for mac to continue it.

Answer (score 0):

Check config or resource file, maybe somewhere space is left.

Also try to use path in quotes like `"obj/Debug/res/ renderers"` or escape space with backslash `obj/Debug/res/\ renderers`